# How to add row separator to grid view in Android?

Tags: android, gridview, shelve

I want to add row separators in GridView. Basically I'm making a shelf app in which shelf will look like this:

[image]

so number of columns can vary with device resolution and also when orientation is changed.
How do I achieve this? any tricks ?

I have looked at [Shelves by Romain Guy](https://code.google.com/p/shelves/). But he has some different strategy because there is no need of row separator.

Comment: if you look at that code you will understand that he is  adding row separator to each cell where as if you look at my design it is not possible to break that image and add it to each cell. I need one complete image for whole row.

Comment: did u get any solution for that? Actually I have also the same problem.Please help

Comment: you can use ListView with multiple items in one row and then can write onClickListener for items in a row. That's what I did as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

try this project from google code and browse view the source code:

https://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk

project home page in google code:

https://code.google.com/p/shelves/

and it's already discussed in stack overflow belown post:

[background scrolling with item in gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734635/background-scrolling-with-item-in-gridview/9757501#9757501)

Comment: check my comment above

Comment: @NayAneshGupte you need separator or row background image of gridview?

Comment: I want something similar to list divider but for GridView i.e. for complete row and not for each cell of a GridView .

Comment: @NayAneshGupte can u saw this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6734635/background-scrolling-with-item-in-gridview/9757501#9757501

Comment: i tried it. Funny thing is even if you remove
Rect source = new Rect(0, mShelfHeight - top, mShelfWidth, mShelfHeight);
            Rect dest = new Rect(x, 0, x + mShelfWidth, top );              

            canvas.drawBitmap(background, source, dest, null);  
these lines it doesn't affect view.

Comment: @NayAneshGupte just post ur code will be check it ok!

Comment: @Dinesh If we set background image  layout is broken when scrolling the grid!! But we can scroll to horizontal to avoid this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11174954/how-to-implement-efficiently-a-gridview-layout

Comment: @Dinesh, NayAneshGupte can you please share how to use that shelves library for designing the book shelves.. I'm failed to reverse engineer the shelves gridview code!

Comment: @Subra Romain Guy's shelves is an open source you can look at it.
Also I looked at the solution given in link u specified. And thats the only option I can think of for time being i.e. List view with divider instead of GridView. But managing it is really head ache as compared to simplicity of Grid view.

Comment: I also tried above solution & I'm able to draw to separator between rows in GridView, however when I scroll the gridView, only item items get scrolled not the separator.How to scroll items with separator like listView.?